# Initiating transactions in nem Returns FAILURE_WRONG_NETWORK

Tags: laravel, nem

I have tried with broadcast example . I am getting failure wrong network error from reference

https://gist.github.com/evias/794b14e2af3704ff5371826e9757832b
[image]

and I have tried with key pair generation from this reference too

https://github.com/evias/nem-php but still I couldnt find whats the issue .version number and network id and wallet address what I have mentioned these are in testnet only.Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to version in $txData

"version"   => -1744830463,

Answer (score -1):

You might be using wrong networkId.
you want to create tx on TEST_NET. but sample page is on MAIN_NET(104).